# Jquery if then statement for css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to check whether a `div` with a CSS `class="x"` has `height="auto"`

If yes I want (with a jQuery script) the `css-class="a"` removed from all elements with the `css-class="y"`

If not the script does not have to do anything. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
if ($('div.x').css('height') === 'auto') {
    $('.y').removeClass('a');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('div.x').css('height') === 'auto') {
    $('.y').removeClass('a');
  }   

});
```

You may need to do that within a each() call