# How check some class has background color or not and change background color if it has

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have class like this

```
 <div class="Ratsheet-destination-detail"></div>
    $(".Ratsheet-destination-detail").css("backgroundColor", #5B815B);
```

Now "Ratsheet-destination-detail"  has red background color.

How i can check this has background color and if it has then change its background color to "#616161"

Thanks.......

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160617/jquery-if-then-statement-for-css-value

Comment: Can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411187/how-to-check-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your colors are going to come back as rgb values. So check the rgb value of the background color. If its red `rgb(255, 0, 0)` , change it to green.

```
var el = $('.Ratsheet-destination-detail');

if(el.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
    el.css('background-color','green');
}​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nQCme/)**

With the op's edit this *should* work if I understand correctly. This will change it to green if the bg is red or grey.

```
var el = $('.Ratsheet-destination-detail');

if(el.css('background-color') == 'rgb(97, 97, 97)' || el.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
    el.css('background-color','green');
}​
```

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nQCme/2/)**

Comment: @yaha not sure if this is what you're after but Ive updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.css` method will tell you what the old color is from within an anonymous function:

```
$(".Ratsheet-destination-detail").css("background-color", function( index, old ){
  // If current is red, set to green, else set to red
  return $.Color(old).is("red") ? "green" : "red" ;
});
```

Here that I am using the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color), `$.Color()` to assist in working with colors. Without it you would have to handle colors in an RGB (or possible RGBA) format, such as `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, which could be a bit confusing at times.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/egemaf/2/edit

In order to use the jQuery Color plugin, you'll need to download and reference the source from your project, like you do with jQuery (assuming you're not using a CDN):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Swapping Background Colors with jQuery and jQuery Color</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Ratsheet-destination-detail">
      <p>Hello, World.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $(".Ratsheet-destination-detail").css("background-color", function(i, old){
        // If current is red, set to green, else set to red
        return $.Color(old).is("red") ? "green" : "red" ;
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Loktar Prior to any color being set, [jQuery will report](http://jsbin.com/iqureb/edit#javascript,html) `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` as the background color. This was my mistake.

Comment: @yaha If you want to use `$.Color`, you will need to add `<script/>` reference to it on your page like you did with jQuery.

Comment: @yaha See the bottom of my answer for setup instructions.